# telegram bot api. Как отключить стандартную клавиатуру (Java)?

Tags: java, api, telegram, бот

Пишу на Java. Есть ли способ отключить стандартную клавиатуру в telegram bot api? Чтобы юзер не мог ввести ничего кроме вариантов из ReplyKeyboardMarkup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отключить вы ее не сможете, это системная штука. Можно свернуть ее, но пользователю она будет доступна и он сможет ее развернуть.

Согласно [документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup), `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` имеет булево `one_time_keyboard`, которому если задать `true`, то бот попросит клиента свернуть системную клавиатуру и будут доступны варианты из клавиатуры бота.